# 'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install rubygems on my windows7 pc. I've download the **rubygems-2.4.1.zip** from https://rubygems.org/pages/download. Now I'm trying to install rubygems through the command:

```
ruby setup.rb
```

But I see the error:

```
'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

How can I use 'ruby' command on my pc?
Downloaded **rubygems-2.4.1.zip** does not contain any exe file, through which I can install it. I'm a beginner. Please help me.

Comment: It begs the question - do you have the ruby itself? If no, go ahead and install this: http://rubyinstaller.org/ it will have rubygems pre-installed.

Comment: that's not a question about programming. please use http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ for configuration-related questions

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but do yourself a favor and create a partition with a UNIX OS.

Comment: Have you changed your path at all?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I solved it-I installed rubyinstaller.exe, then devkit.

Answer (score 0):

### Try RubyInstaller on Win32 Platforms

Rubygems is a package manager for Ruby, which is a per-requisite that you may or may not have properly installed on your OS. Installing Ruby on Windows *properly* is tricky; your best bet is to use [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) to install Ruby and Rubygems, and make sure to read the [RubyInstaller FAQ](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/FAQ).

Good luck!